# Localhost and fopen

Tags: codeigniter, mamp, fopen

We are now working in a local environment, rather than working live, which is a good thing.  However, I've run into a hiccup I don't know how to fix.  My code (CodeIgniter) looks like this:

```
if (!is_dir(base_url() . 'channel-partners/html/camera-registration/' . $name_url)) {
        mkdir(base_url() . 'channel-partners/html/camera-registration/' . $name_url);
}

$handle = fopen('/path/to/file/channel-partners/html/camera-registration/' . $name_url . '/index.html', 'w') or die('Can\'t open file');
fwrite($handle, $html);
fclose($handle);
```

But since I'm running MAMP, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` equals Applications/MAMP/htdocs, so that won't work.  So what can I do to write a file in PHP that would work in both a production environment and a local environment?

Comment: $name_url and $html are defined elsewhere.  They are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `FCPATH` or `APPPATH` constants.

`FCPATH` will give you the path to the directory where the front controller is located (index.php).

`APPPATH` will give you the path to the application directory.

Usage:

```
fopen(FCPATH . 'path/relative/to/frontcontroller/etc/' . $name_url . '/index.html', 'w') ...
```